# R remove words from sentences in dataframe

Tags: r, stringr

I have one dataframe with two columns which each containing sentences and I would like to subtract one from the other. I somehow can't easily find a method to do the following:

```
> c1 <- c("A short story","Not so short")
> c2 <- c("A short", "Not so")
> data.frame(c1, c2)
```

which should give the result of c1 - c2

```
"story","short"
```

Any ideas are helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_remove` which is vectorized

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(c3 = str_remove_all(c1, c2))
         c1      c2     c3
#1 A short story A short  story
#2  Not so short  Not so  short
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
c1 <- c("A short story","Not so short")
c2 <- c("A short", "Not so")

dat <- data.frame(c1, c2)
dat$c3 <- purrr::map2_chr(c1, c2, ~ trimws(gsub(.y, "", .x)))
dat
#>              c1      c2    c3
#> 1 A short story A short story
#> 2  Not so short  Not so short
```